# PHP function showing wrong time in WordPress

Tags: php, date-time, xampp, timezones

My local WordPress installation on XAMPP seems to have a wrong time setting. When I do

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

I get **2017-02-21 10:46:43** as result. However my PCs time really is **2017-02-21 11:46:43**, so my WordPress is one hour behind.

Now I already did, what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359451/xampp-php-date-function-time-is-different-from-local-machine-time) and changed **date.timezone** in the **php.ini** to my timezone and restarted the apache afterwards, since I thought the problem might be cause by XAMPP. But still I get the wrong time displayed.

I also went to **settings -> general** in WordPress and changed the timezone there to the correct one. The local time shown there is correct:

*"Local time is 2017-02-21 11:46:43"*

But when I use the function, it's still wrong. Do you have any idea, what else could cause this problem?

Comment: How is it in any way related to wordpress (except for the most none important one that you run wordpress on the same server)?

Answer (score 8):

`date()` is a `PHP` function depending on your server settings. You can go around that by using the WordPress function:

```
current_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

This function takes the settings in `wp-admin` into account.

Answer (score 0):

use wordpress functions to get time according to WordPress settings and time zone such as `the_time` and `the_date`

```
 the_date('F j, Y');
 the_time('g:i a');
```

Comment: Nope - the_date() and related show the *publication date* of the current post, not the current time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Wordpress overrides the php Timezone to save all dates as UTC.
But they also do a poor job in converting it back to local time.

I have run into the same problem and did some testing to find a solution.

1st of all this is not a PHP timezone Problem, to confirm this I put a test.php into my theme folder and opened it directly (/wp-content/themes/theme/test.php)

if I use the date() function in this file the time is correct.

but if I put this lines into e.g. my themes home.php

```
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
print current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I get the wrong time when I visit the Homepage.

date() returns UTC and current_time() return the time of the right timezone but it does not include DST so I'm still 1 hour off.

what i ended up doing is this:

```
$row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS timestamp", ARRAY_A);
$timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
```

if your database has the right config for your timezone you can ask your database for the Timestamp.

But this also has some downsides, it will only work if your Database has right timezone and it always does a Query to the database so you should not use it to excessive.